# API to localize a path?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm searching for a way to get all localized paths for one path.

For non-content pages this is quite simple:

```
foreach (language_list() as $language)
  $paths[$language->language] = url(current_path(), array('language' => $language));
}
```

For content pages (node, taxonomy, …) the path might be completely different and things like [translation_path_get_translations()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_path_get_translations/7) seem more like what I need.

Is there a reliable way to get paths to all translations of a page that works whether it's a content-page or not? It feels like there has to be an API-function for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out about [`language_negotiation_get_switch_links($type,$path)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!language.inc/function/language_negotiation_get_switch_links/7). The tricky part is the `$type` argument. The types are defined by implementations of [`hook_language_types_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_language_types_info/7) and at least for my setup `$type = 'language'` does the trick.